# Cant animate image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, animation

Can I somehow animate the image on the left in the picture on the right. 
need a smooth animation.

I found how to do it without the animation. With CSS
-webkit-filter: brightness(1000%);

[image]

Comment: show us your html and css

Comment: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

Answer (score 1):

Just place one image on ot of another and use `fadeOut()` like

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-with-relative-position">
    <img1>
    <img2 style="position: absolute;" id="img2">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 $('#img2').fadeOut(1000);
```

For js function you can use any trigger you want like `click`,'hover` etc. And html is just a scheme of what you have to do, not the actual code.